# I've got a D3100 and the mirror broke!! What to do?

Tags: mirror

I have a D3100 and the view finder mirror broke. I just don't know how!! It's in warranty but can I get a replacement?... My father doesn't know yet.. guys please reply fast

Comment: You'll need to take it to a specialist, if you've managed to break the mirror it's likely you've done other damage that you can't see (yet).

Comment: As a father myself, I'd say you should not worry. Things get broken, things get fixed. Take the camera to your father and tell him it got broken. Hiding it is not a good choice.

Comment: your father will find out anyway, so best 'fess up and come clean. Most likely it'll cost you a few years of pocket money as it's exceedingly unlikely the repairs will be covered by warranty (stupidity isn't covered by warranty...).

Answer (score 3):

Your D3100 will need to be serviced by a trained technician. Whatever caused the mirror to break could have damaged other sensitive components as well. Besides, Nikon no longer sells most parts for their DSLRs except to Nikon Factory authorized repair centers.